# How to get one part of a directory path

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a path which I get through `=INFO("Directory")` (for example "C:\Users\username\Documents\") and I want to extract username that is between 2nd and 3rd slash, it can be of any word length so I want a general formula for extracting it.

Comment: Supply some sample data, what do you actually get from your formula and what result do you want? As it stands your question is to vague to answer.

Comment: Are you specifically trying to extract only the username?

Answer (score 3):

The following formula will extract the user name from a directory path in cell A1 that is the user directory (C:\Users\username) or a subdirectory of it.

```
=MID(A1,FIND("\",A1,4)+1,FIND("\",A1,FIND("\",A1,4)+1)-FIND("\",A1,4)-1)
```

The formula finds the second "\" by starting its search at the 4th position (because the first "\" is usually at the 3rd position).

Keep in mind that the workbook could be in a directory that is not part of the user directory (e.g. it could be in "D:\Docs").

If you simply want to get the name of the current user, you can do that in VBA using `Environ$("UserName")`. For example, create a user defined function like this (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6934266/4424957)

```
Public Function UserName()
    UserName = Environ$("UserName")
End Function
```